# Toggle components with radio buttons in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have 3 radio buttons on my profile component that need to toggle between read, reading, and wantToRead components. How can I achieve this?

I think I need to get the input value to set it as a condition for v-show.

```
<template>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="toggle_radio">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" value="first_toggle" name="toggle_option" v-model="picked">
        <input type="radio" checked class="toggle_option" id="second_toggle" value="second_toggle" name="toggle_option" v-model="picked">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="third_toggle" value="third_toggle" name="toggle_option" v-model="picked">
        <label for="first_toggle"><p>First Button</p></label>
        <label for="second_toggle"><p>Second Button</p></label>
        <label for="third_toggle"><p>Third Button</p></label>
        <div class="toggle_option_slider">
        <span>Picked: {{ picked }} </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <app-read v-show="picked.first_toggle"></app-read>
        <app-reading v-show="picked.second_toggle"></app-reading>
        <app-want-to-read v-show="picked.third_toggle"></app-want-to-read>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Read from './Read.vue'
    import Reading from './Reading.vue'
    import WantToRead from './Want_To_Read.vue'

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                picked: []
            };
        },
        components: {
            appRead: Read,
            appReading: Reading,
            appWantToRead: WantToRead
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [examples](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio) in the documentation?

Comment: Yes, let me add some code. I think I need to somehow get the input value to set up a condition in v-show.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, you should initialize `picked` to `null`. It will only have one scalar value, it will not be an array.

The conditions for your `v-show`s should be like this:

```
v-show="picked === 'third_toggle'"
```

you want to check the value stored in `picked`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I actually used the dynamic components from your initial comment. So now I have 2 working solutions!